# why redhat repository still offers 2-years old boost?

Tags: rhel

I"ve installed RHEL 7.1 which was just released (several weeks ago). I wonder that it still offers boost 1.53 which was released more than 2 years ago http://www.boost.org/users/history/

```
yum list | grep boost
boost.x86_64                           1.53.0-23.el7          @rhel-7-server-rpms
boost-atomic.x86_64                    1.53.0-23.el7          @rhel-7-server-rpms
boost-chrono.x86_64                    1.53.0-23.el7          @rhel-7-server-rpms
boost-context.x86_64                   1.53.0-23.el7          @rhel-7-server-rpms
boost-date-time.x86_64                 1.53.0-23.el7          @rhel-7-server-rpms
boost-devel.x86_64                     1.53.0-23.el7          @rhel-7-server-rpms
boost-filesystem.x86_64                1.53.0-23.el7          @rhel-7-server-rpms
...
```

- Why RHEL doesn't update boost in their repository for a years?
- How safe it would be to compile and use latest version (1.57) myself?
- Am I correct that it would be a good advice - never use boost from RHEL 7 repository because it always ooold, just compile latest version yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want more recent software, you probably should use some other distribution. RHEL is an enterprise distribution, and does not ship the newest software, probably because it is more throughly tested to shake out all the bugs. Upgrading the installed Boost  version may or may not be an option, depending on what other packages in the distribution depend on it. An alternative is to install a more recent version of Boost locally.

Comment: how safe it is to download 1.57 compile and install it myself? should I in addition install 1.53 from repository because other packages depend on it?

Comment: @javapowered if the Boost 1.53 is required, it would be automatically installed. You don't need to install it specifically. It actually looks like you have some Boost packages installed already. You could install Boost 1.57 locally.